# The discriminator is classifying everything as fake. What does it mean?

Tags: gan, conditional

I am using a conditional GAN with a relativistic loss function for both generator and discriminator (https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.00734). Before I added the relativistic part, the discriminator converges very fast to always classifying right, which got me thinking that maybe the gradients were not changing anymore, and the generator was not learning anymore. After adding the relativistic loss, the discriminator converges to the state of classifying everything as fake. Should I worry about this, even if the generated images look pretty good? What does it mean in terms of training and learning?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Without knowing more about your problem, the key part of your post seems to be that the generated images look pretty good. My question to you: so they look good enough to be useful?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The images look good enough to be useful, yes. But it would be nice to interpret the loss of the discriminator..

Comment: The images *are* fake, right?

Comment: Yes, the images are fake.

Comment: The discriminator is correctly identifying the images as fake. What's the problem?

Comment: It is  classifying the real images as fake as well. My understanding is that, if the training is converging, the probability of classifying fake and real should be 50-50%.

Comment: How many fake images do you have, compared to real images? I wonder if this could be a matter of there being so many fake images that the discriminator says, "Yeah, basically everything is fake," and gives high values for the probability of being fake. (More technically, I wonder if a high prior probability of being fake means that the posterior probabilities are fake, too. If the images look good, that indicates minimal differences between fake and real images, too.)